# How to extract the array index value from getelementptr instruction of llvm

Tags: llvm

```
array[5] = 20;
```

equivalent LLVM IR

```
%arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %2, i64 5
store i32 20, i32* %arrayidx, align 4
```

How to extract 5 from the LLVM IR ?

Comment: You mean using the C++ API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `GetElementPtrInst* GEP`, you can access the indices using `GEP->getOperand(i)` (with operand 0 being the pointer, and the remaining operands being the indices). To get the value 5, you can then check that the index is a `ConstantInt` and if so get its value, like this:

```
if (ConstantInt *CI = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(GEP->getOperand(1)) {
    uint64_t Idx = CI->getZExtValue();
}
```

Comment: What if it isn't a ConstantInt and is an instruction instead? This happens when we have `a = 5; array[a] = 0;`. How do we access the value of `a`?

Comment: You can't access the value of a, because it can depend on input that is not known at compile time, such as user input.

Comment: The answer is not complete for the other questioners. How to get "GetElementPtrInst* GEP"?