# Extracting array index variable and for loop iteration variable in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I want to write a LLVM pass to get array indexing info and for loop index info of a program. Consider the following very simple program which accesses a 2D array.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, arr2d[5][10];
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            arr2d[i][j] = i * j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The array is being indexed by variables i and j. The loops are also being indexed by variables i and j. Is it possible to know the array indexing variables and loop control variables from a LLVM pass given I have the IR file of the program?

From the IR file it seems that these values can be backtracked to i and j. But not sure how to do it in a pass?

For example, the in the IR file of the program it is visible that it might be backtracked like this:

GEP calculating final lvalue:

```
%21 = getelementptr inbounds [10 x i32], [10 x i32]* %18, i64 0, i64 %20
```

Tracking j:

```
%20 = sext i32 %19 to i64
%19 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
%3 = alloca i32, align 4 // Allocation of j
```

Tracking i:

```
%18 = getelementptr inbounds [5 x [10 x i32]], [5 x [10 x i32]]* %4, i64 0, i64 %17
%17 = zext i32 %16 to i64
%16 = load i32, i32* %2
%2 = alloca i32, align 4 // Allocation of i
```

Is it possible to do backtrack to %2 and %3 here for array index and loop index? This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836212/how-to-extract-the-array-index-value-from-getelementptr-instruction-of-llvm) shows how to get the constant index but not the variable index.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes. Mostly.

A loop generally looks like this in IR: There are four blocks, which I'll call a, b c and d.

Block a precedes the loop. Often a sets up the initial values of the loop's variables, but the important thing is that a precedes the loop. In LLVM-speak, it [dominates](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DominatorTree.html) the loop, which means that if the loop is executed, then a has been executed.

Block b contains the loop test. It generally contains a [phi](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1PHINode.html) that is the current value of a variable used to control/end the loop, such as i and j in this case, and it ends with a conditional branch to c and d.

Block c contains the loop body. It ends with a branch to b.

Block d is whatever is executed after the loop. It's not relevant to the loop, except that knowing about it helps you understand the general structure. Many loops contain more block than this (for example c will be several blocks if there's an inner loop), but this is the general idea. LLVM contains code to help you find these, even in complicated cases, look at some uses of [LoopInfo](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoopInfo.html) to find some examples.

Block b is the interesting one in your case. The conditional branch that ends it contains an operand that's somehow produced from the phi in the same block. There may be several phis, in that case the loop variable is the phi that eventually leads to the branch. (If several phis are involved in the branch, you have some unusual code on your hands, which isn't at all unusual. You'll run into an unusual loop well before you've processed a hundred commonplace ones, and have to decide what to do.)

Finding the loop variable probably involves a recursive search of the values used to produce condition operand in the conditional branch. This isn't as complicated as it sounds. You may see that the condition operand in the branch is an instruction in the same block, and it's a load, and the pointer operand of the load is another instruction in the same block, and it's a gep, and the index operand of the gep is the phi. A chain like that is typical.

It can be a little more complicated, but this should be enough to write enough code to pass your first unit test. (LoopInfo provides information to help you with complications such as the null pointer check in `int g=0;while(e && e->f[g++]){…}`, which you can add as a unit test later, but not right away.)